# How to use 12voip.com (Betamax) SIP service for calling and sendingSMS?

Tags: software-recommendation

Could anyone help me with configuring any Linux softphones for use with SIP betamax services? In Windows, I was using 12voip.com to make calls and send SMS. However I have failed to correctly configure Linphone and Ekiga so far. All the instructions in Internet seem to relate to old versions of Ekiga. I have also tried the original 12voip (Betamax) client with Wine, it installs, runs but fails to log in. Thanks, guys!

@Administrators: Please, replace the 'software-recommendation' with some reasonable tags (e.g. betamax, sip, softphone) to this question. I cannot create tags yet.

Answer (score 1):

Install Ekiga from software center then run it and edit account information .
Enter registrar to sip.12voip.com, your username (put the same in account name), and your password.

[image]

Comment: This is a screenshot of what program?

Comment: "Install **Ekiga** from software center"  First sentence, @texnic.

Comment: Well, in my Ekiga the "Edit account" dialogue looks different, that's why I thought I might be missing something. For example, my one asks for a User *and* an Authentication User. May be it's hidden under "More options" in the screenshot, but I don't have a "less options" button. The problem is, I have already tried everything mentioned here and it still doesn't work. That's why I am trying to eliminate any differences. Please don't get annoyed with me, I am annoyed with this problem for months myself already, have always to switch to Windows to make a call :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use empathy for sip protocol as well. You need to add telepathy-sofiasip package.

Just do

`sudo apt-get install telepathy-sofiasip libtelepathy-farsight0 python-tpfarsight`

And in accounts section add your information.

[image]

Comment: This done... However, how do I now make a call? In which format should I enter the phone number if my provider is 12voip.com (http://www.12voip.com/en/sipp.html)

Comment: @texnic: SIP is a bit like an Email client.  To set it up, you need to know your **username/password/server** and of course your email address so that people can reply to you.  But when you *make a call* you dial the other people's telephone number.

Comment: @sladen: In which format do I enter the phone number? Starting with +?

Answer (score 0):

Slfphone is simple for use and it is working properly on Ubuntu 13.04 and connects to 12voip easily. It can be installed from Software Center.

These are the settings:

- alias my_alias
- Protocol – SIP
- Host name: sip.12voip.com
- User name: voip_user_name
- Password: voip_password
- Proxy: sip.12voip.com
- User agent: SFLphone

On advanced settings, enable Using STUN and put:

*STUN server URL*: **stun.12voip.com**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Ekiga 4.0.1 and 12voip (I'm translating so the actual text in the GUI might be somewhat different)

- **Name:** *account-name-whatever-you-want*
- **Register server:** sip.12voip.com
- **User:** *yourusername*@sip.12voip.com
- **Authentication user:** *yourusername*
- **Password:** *yourpassword*
- **Timeout:** *default-3600-is-fine*
- Check **Enable account**
- **OK**
- Wait until it says **Registered** in the Accounts dialog

To place a call just dial the number and it should autocomplete to something like sip:*numberwithinternationaldialingcode*@sip.12voip.com